# Feed a select with json

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I do an ajax call to a spring server, I got this

```
{
  "colors" : [ {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "A1 Classic"
  } ],
  "dimensions" : [ {
    "id" : 2,
    "createdAt" : null,
    "updatedAt" : null,
    "name" : "1,2m"
  }, {
    "id" : 3,
    "createdAt" : null,
    "updatedAt" : null,
    "name" : "100"
  } ],
  "products" : [ {
    "id" : 6,
    "createdAt" : null,
    "updatedAt" : null,
    "productTypes" : 1,
    "name" : "test-bloc"
  } ]
}
```

I would like to take content of colors dimensions, products and put it in their select html component.

I found this who seem interesant

https://dzone.com/articles/populate-a-jquery-dropdown-from-ajax

```
jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "get",
    url: "/menu/search-reports/producttypes/" + productTypesId,
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        helpers.buildDropdown(
            jQuery.parseJSON(data.dimensions),
            $('#searchSamplesDimensions'),
            'Select an option'
        );

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status) {
    }
});
```

When code is running, I got

```
Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

Comment: `jQuery.parseJSON(data.dimensions)` is parse here necessary?

Comment: That error means that it's likely your JSON is already an object, and therefore not really JSON

Comment: cool, but the solution are?

Comment: You can do a loop for for dimensions products and colors...  and add element in your select